# Position buttons in control array

Tags: c#

I'm trying to recall the buttons I created and position them on arrays that hold its location but FindControl gives Error.

```
 'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'FindControl' and no extension method 
 'FindControl' accepting a first argument of type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing
 a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My code is under a timer1.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...
        if ...
        {
            ...
            Button btn = new Button();
            {
                btn.Name = "Btn-" + tail.ToString();
                btn.Height = 10;
                btn.Width = 10;
                btn.Tag = tail+1;
                btn.Location = new Point((stailX[1]-1)*10, (stailY[1] - 1) * 10);
            }
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
        ...
        for (int i = 1; i <= tail; i++)
        {
            ((Button)this.FindControl("Btn-" + tail.ToString())).Location = new Point((stailX[i] - 1) * 10, (stailY[i] - 1) * 10);
        }

    }
```

I've omitted parts of code not important. Please help.

Comment: FindControl works for this.Controls collection

Comment: I don't use Findcontrol() because it very efficient.  Usually make my own List Object like : List<Button> myButtons = new List<Button>();  Then search the list object.  So after this.Controls.Add(btn) add myButtons.Add(btn);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would include putting the controls in an array or a list for easy access later. Here is an example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();
    int i = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(20 , i* 30);
        buttonList.Add(btn); // add instance to list

        this.Controls.Add(btn); // add the same instance to the form


        for (int j = 0; j < buttonList.Count; ++j)
        {
            //  do whatever you want here
            buttonList[j].Text = j.ToString();
        }

    }


}
```

This way you don't need to find the control you want on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the same, by iterating through each controls in the form using `this.Controls`, and can be more specifically by filtering them using `.OfType<Button>()`. To make sure that those controls are dynamically created with specific Ids you can add the conditions as well. The code for this will looks like the following:

```
int i = 1;
foreach (Button childButton in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    if (childButton.Name.StartsWith("Btn-"))
    {
        childButton.Location = new Point((stailX[i] - 1) * 10, (stailY[i] - 1) * 10);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Hope that it will help you

Comment: Don't I need the counter i for this? I need i cause position depends on array content.

Comment: Yes You have to define `i` to access `stailX`, see the updates in the answer

Answer (score 0):

How about Controls.Find("controlname", true)